# mysql import continue in previous database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have tried import database by command line in mysql. It was big one having size of 2Gb. The import was stopped in middle of some where with error like

```
Error 2006 at line 14425, Mysql has gone away.
```

I checked tables, total table is around 450. But only 363 tables are imported.

Anyway I'm going to try again with increasing `max_allowed_packet` and increasing `timeout`.

The question is, can I import the database in previous one, so that It can continue where it was stopped..? or import in new database..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379079/import-mysql-data-interrupted-how-to-resume

Comment: i think it does not matter both will take same time. since, .sql dump contains drop table before it create a table in your DB and inserts the data.

Comment: There's an active thread at the moment on a similar issue; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379079/import-mysql-data-interrupted-how-to-resume

Answer (score 0):

The error "Mysql has gone away" is usually a sign that your client has lost connection to the mysql server, sometimes because the server is misconfigured and has crashed - happens more than you think.

Also make sure that your dump does not contain system tables; this would also cause a crash.

Check the mysql server error log, usually at /var/log/mysqld.log - you can check where this is on your sever with;

```
SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'LOG_ERROR';
```